# How to upgrade MySQLi version on WAMP Server?

Tags: mysqli, upgrade, wampserver

Hi fellow programmers,

I just installed WAMP Server latest version (2.4) on my laptop but I see that it comes with MySQLi 5.0.

I wanted to upgrade to MySQLi 5.5 because this is the version installed on my online hosting account, so I won't have problems later when I move things online.

I recently created a script on local wamp server and when I moved it online, there were a ton of errors and things to fix due to mysli version changes.

Can we upgrade mysqli version on wamp server?
Or is there any easier way I can connect/work locally so changes I make locally are reflected directly on my online server?

My sites are hosted at Namecheap.

Comment: you are probably talking of mysql, not mysqli

Comment: I'm talking for MySQLi as it appears from phpinfo()   - the mysqli section, 
but I'm not very much into this stuff so I may be wrong.
Either way, I see WAMP server comes with an older version and I just wanted it to match the latest version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have confused something. Mysqli doesn't have any version number of it's own and it cannot be "upgraded", as it's just a part of PHP.

Also, numbers do not matter too much. I am sure you'll be as happy with whatever 5.0 as well as with 5.5 of the same.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this. I managed to make things work on the online server after resolving many issues.